# How to deploy my project from my personal sandbox to vercel

Tags: deployment

I have developed first project in my sandbox.Project is related to timer. After clicking on start timer should start. Getting output as expected but Dont know process of deploying . Please help me in how to deploy code from my sandbox to vercel.

Help me in deploying code.